# How to add a rate and review option to windows 8 store app using javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to add a rate and review option to windows 8 store app using javascript/html.I want to add this in charm settings as well as app bar. When user clicks on it , user should be navigated to the page in windows store to rate and review it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Rate and Review"  on the Settings Charm is automatically added to our application after we submit it to the Windows Store

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so once you download the app, go to the settings and click on the rate and review button. You can also directly search the app in the store and rate/review it there after you've installed it.

Arun

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the app in the Windows 8 store, then in the LEFT MOST collumn scroll down, there you can choose a Star under "Rate this app".

If you've clicked on "rate and review" and are seeing reviews, you're too far and you can't leave a review from that page. Just go back one page and scroll down in the left most collumn.

Took me some effort to find myself, I guess Microsoft has made Windows 8 store with having higher resolutions in mind.

Comment: He's actually asking how to display a button to direct a user to rate an application, not how to rate an application himself.